# Update profile picture and delete the current one. PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible in PHP to update a profile picture and delete the current one from the folder  and its link from the database?

If yes, please help: I managed to delete the link from the database but the picture in the folder remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s assume that you have a folder called Images where you uploaded your pictures
So in that folder there is an image called test.jpg . this code will delete  that image in the folder .
@David Rabinowitz  thanks for giving him a great answer which uses a database but I am also trying to give him a second example which does not use a database maybe it will also help him

```
<?php 
$file ="test.jpg";
$filedel="images/".$file;
if(file_exists($file)){
echo "file exits";
unlink($filedel);
else{
echo "the file you want to delete does nto exist ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function.

```
//before deleting the path from database, get it in one variable using php
$filename = path from database;
unlink($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP `unlink` function is used to del the existing file from directory

```
$filename = 'define file name here with proper path';
unlink($filename);
```